# showModalBottomSheet not working properly within nested go router navigation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet, flutter-go-router

I am using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) package for **Navigation 2.0**, but while running **showModalBottomSheetFunction**, the view is not showing correctly. Here is the picture:  [image]

By the way, I am using nested navigation for bottom navigation bar.

I was expecting that ModalBottomSheet should look proper.

Comment: Can you share some code where you're implementing bottom navbar and modalBottomSheet?

Comment: What do you expect ? the navigation bar to be covered by the bottom sheet ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The navigation bar is probably above your navigation tree (the nested one). To  cover the navigation bar with the bottom sheet use: `useRootNavigator: true`

```dart
    showModalBottomSheet(
        useRootNavigator: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return const Text("hello");
        });
```